# libpcap performance and behavior differences between Ubuntu 14.40 and CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, libpcap, centos6.5

I have been running a tcpdump based script on Ubuntu for some time, and recently I have been asked to run it on CentOS 6.5 and I'm noticing some very interesting differences

I'm running tcpdump 4.6.2, libpcap 1.6.2 on both setups, both are actually running on the same hardware (dual booted)

I'm running the same command on both OS'.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -s 0 -nei eth9 -w /mnt/tmpfs/eth9_rx.pcap -B 2000000
```

From "free -k", I see about 2G allocated on Ubuntu

Before:

```
free -k
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
```

Mem:      65928188    1337008   64591180       1164      26556      68596
-/+ buffers/cache:    1241856   64686332
Swap:     67063804          0   67063804

After: 
 free -k
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      65928188    3341680   62586508       1160      26572      68592
-/+ buffers/cache:    3246516   62681672
Swap:     67063804          0   67063804

```
expr 3341680 - 1337184
```

2004496

One CentOS, I see twice the amount of memory (4G) being allocated from the same command

Before:

```
free -k
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
```

Mem:      16225932     394000   15831932          0      15308      85384
-/+ buffers/cache:     293308   15932624
Swap:      8183804          0    8183804

After:
free -k
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16225932    4401652   11824280          0      14896      84884
-/+ buffers/cache:    4301872   11924060
Swap:      8183804          0    8183804

```
expr 4401652 - 394000
```

4007652

From the command, I'm listening against an interface and dumping into a RAMdisk.

On Ubuntu, I can capture packets at line rate for large size packets (10G, 1024 byte frames)

But on CentOS, I can only capture packets at 60% of line rate (10G, 1024 byte frames)

Also, both OS's are running the same version of NIC drivers and driver configurations.

My goal is to achieve the same performance on CentOS as I have with Ubuntu.

I googled around and there seems to be the magic of libpcap behaving differently with different kernels. I'm curious if there's any kernel side options I have to tweek on the CentOS side to achieve the same performance on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered. According to Guy Harris from tcpdump/libpcap, the difference is due to CentOS6.5 running 2.6.X kernel. Below is his response:

"
3.2 introduced the TPACKET_V3 version of the "T(urbo)PACKET" memory-mapped packet capture mechanism for PF_PACKET sockets; newer versions of libpcap (1.5 and later) support TPACKET_V3 and will use it if the kernel supports it. TPACKET_V3 makes much more efficient use of the capture buffer; in at least one test, it dropped fewer packets. It also might impose less overhead, so that asking for a 2GB buffer takes less kernel memory."